# Django Rest Framework @list_route requires pk

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF 2.4.4 and running into this issue where the `@list_route` decorator requires a `pk`.  Here is my code excerpt:

```
class RunViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = RunSerializer
    queryset = Run.objects.all()

    @list_route()
    def active(self, request, pk):
        '''Return active runs.'''
        qs = Run.objects.all(deleted=False)
        serializer = RunSerializer(qs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

If I try to access the endpoint at `/api/runs/active` I get a `404 error`. It only works if I give a `pk` such as `/api/runs/1/active`.  Since `@list_route` is supposed to operate on a collection, why do I need to give it a `pk`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with the Extended Routers of [DRF extensions](https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions/issues/30).

Comment: Accept your answer if it is solved. You may also want to describe the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote @djangozone. I can't accept my answer right now, it tells me to wait until tomorrow.  My issue was that I expected to be able to access my list endpoint at /api/runs/active but it didn't work with ExtendedDefaultRouter.  I'm not sure what the problem is with it from reading the ticket I linked, but it looks like they are still using the deprecated '@action' decorator and don't have plans to support '@linked_route' anytime soon.

Comment: Hi @ybendana, I ran into the same problem. Were you able to find a workaroud for this?

Comment: Hi @IndradhanushGupta, sorry I didn't find a workaround and I'm not using the Extended Router anymore.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone still have this problem, you can use solution suggested [here](https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions/issues/70#issuecomment-72463001).

> If you want to use nesting facilities you should mixin
>   NestedRouterMixin into your router.

What I did:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from rest_framework_extensions.routers import NestedRouterMixin


class NestedDefaultRouter(NestedRouterMixin, DefaultRouter):
    pass

# Then you can use your router as usual
router = NestedDefaultRouter()
```